# ET Subscriber added via SOAP API, but does not appear in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, php

I am using a client's ExactTarget credentials (API User = yes) to add email subscribers using the SOAP API from my webapp. The API call returns a "Subscriber created" msg, but the subscriber info doesn't appear when logging into ET's webapp.

I've tried resending the API call with the same email and get a "Subscriber already exists" response, but still the subscriber is not visible.

From ET's webapp itself, if I try to create a subscriber with the same email, I again get the "already exists" response. If I then view the properties for that already existing user, the email address I originally sent from my webapp is indeed there.

** I also used ET's webapp ( same credentials as my webapp ) to create a subscriber using the wizard. The wizard claims the subscriber was created but again, the info is not visible in any list (even "All Subscribers"). The counter that displays the number of subscribers per list does not change either. **

Feels like some kind of fundamental permissions/settings issue for the client's account or the "business unit" this client is a part of.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check your [business unit filter](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/subscriber_filters_in_an_enterprise_20_account/).  If you're not setting that field properly, your subscriber won't show in the business unit.

Comment: Thank you! That was it.

Unless we set a specific attribute for that new subscriber that associated the email address with the correct "child account" then the email would get added to the parent account.

Comment: Sweet.  Please mark your question as answered.  Also, in an E2.0 all subscribers are at the parent level.